# How to pass 2 arrays as params from controller to view

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2, zend-form

I am working with the zend framework and am trying to create an edit contacts page. When the page loads I want to display a form with the current stored values for those fields.

I am trying to pass a form and the database values to my view so that I can pre-populate the form with the current values for those fields. I can pass the form or the array of contacts. But when I try to pass both one of the arrays will return null

```
public function editContactAction()
{
    $form = new EditContact();
    $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('contactId');

    $variables = array();
    $contactService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('User\Service\UserService');

    $variables['contacts'] = $contactService->editContact($id);

    return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form), $variables);
}
```

Comment: Well just put `return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form, 'variables' => $variables));`

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. The ViewModel argument is an array, pass your `$variables` array in the arguments array:

```
public function editContactAction()
{
     $form = new EditContact();
     $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('contactId');

     $variables = array();
     $contactService = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('User\Service\UserService');

     $variables['contacts'] = $contactService->editContact($id);

     return new ViewModel(array(
         'form' => $form,
         'variables' => $variables
     ));
}
```

And in your view, you can access this `$variables` array this way:

```
$this->variables ;
```

Comment: you are missing a `,`

Comment: @Unex Thkx, fixed.

Comment: I have tried this but then the variables array is returning null in the view. In my view I want to set the initial form values to the values in my variables array.  My variables array has some data such as firstname, lastname, etc set

Comment: @gibbles To initiate the form's values, you'd better bind your form with an object as described [in the docs](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html).